# Calling function to new function in Python

Tags: python, function-call

I have tried this several different ways, I am still fairly new to Python so go easy on me.  I am trying to execute a script where the user can choose to import a list from a plaintext file, or input a list manually, and the script will return the median and mode of the data.

The problem I am having is that my median and mode functions are not recognizing the reference to the raw data, and the main function isn't recognizing the median and mode from their respective functions.

I guess it's safe to say I am not calling these functions correctly, but frankly I just dont know how.  Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
def choice():
    ##Choose user input type
    start = input("Please select your input method by typing 'file' or 'manual' in all lower-case letters: ")
    # Import File Type
    userData = []
    if start == "file":
        fileName = input("Please enter the file name with the file's extension, e.g. ' numbers.txt': ")
        userData = open(fileName).read().splitlines()
        return userData
        userData.close()
    # Manual Entry Type
    elif start == "manual":
        while True:
            data = float(input("Please enter your manual data one item at a time, press enter twice to continue: "))
            if data == "":
                break
            userData = data
            return userData
    # Error
    else:
        print("You have entered incorrectly, please restart program")


def median(medianData):
    numbers = []
    for line in (choice(userData)):
        listData = line.split()
        for word in listData:
            numbers.append(float(word))

    # Sort the list and print the number at its midpoint
    numbers.sort()
    midpoint = len(numbers) // 2
    print("The median is", end=" ")
    if len(numbers) % 2 == 1:
        medianData = (numbers[midpoint])
        return medianData
    else:
        medianData = ((numbers[midpoint] + numbers[midpoint - 1]) / 2)
        return medianData


def mode(modeData):
    words = []
    for line in (choice(userData)):
        wordsInLine = line.split()
        for word in wordsInLine:
            words.append(word.upper())
    theDictionary = {}
    for word in words:
        number = theDictionary.get(word, None)
        if number == None:
            theDictionary[word] = 1
        else:
            theDictionary[word] = number + 1


    theMaximum = max(theDictionary.values())
    for key in theDictionary:
        if theDictionary[key] == theMaximum:
            theMaximum = modeData
            break
        return modeData

def main():
    print("The median is", (median(medianData)))
    print("The mode is", (mode(modeData)))
```

Comment: Could you include the traceback? Also, there's code for functions, but nothing outside of them is calling them. When I run this code, it does not return errors

Comment: Are you a matlab user? You don't need to put the return variable in  the argument list of a Python function. Define your functions instead as e.g. `def mode():` Also, you called `choice` with an argument, but define it as not taking any. `choice()` is the correct way to call your function

Comment: do you call your script with `python myscript.py` from command line. If so you need to add an dunder main, meaning: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: @Carcigenicate It doesn't give a traceback error, when I try to run it is jumps to "Process finished with exit code 0" and does nothing else.

Comment: @samusa No this is a main.py script.  It's meant to be executed within the IDE.

Comment: You don't seem to call `main()`, that's not done automatically in Python.

Comment: @bereal Thank you, at least now I'm getting callback errors. Errors are as follows:  Traceback (most recent call last): ...\main.py", line 76, in <module> main()
 \main.py", line 73, in main print("The median is", (median(medianData)))
NameError: name 'medianData' is not defined

Comment: You should also close the file you open in line 8

Comment: @LuisAFK Done, and added it to the page here

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! I think you need to read up a bit more on how functions work. The argument when you *define* a function is a "dummy" local variable whose name matters only in the definition of a function. You need to supply it a variable or constant whose name makes sense where you use it. It is a very good analogy to functions in mathematics which you may have learned about in school. (Note that these points are not specific to python, although the detailed syntax is.)

So when you have `def median(medianData)` you need to use `medianData` in the definition of the function, not `userData`, and when you *call* `median(somevar)` you have to make sure that `somevar` has a value at that point in your program.

As a simpler example:

```py
def doubleMyVariable(x):
   return 2*x
```

How would you use this? You could just put this somewhere in your code:

```py
print(doubleMyVariable(3))
```

which should print out `6`.

Or this:

```py
z = 12
y = doubleMyVariable(z)
print(y)
```

which will print `12`.

You could even do

```py
z = 36
x = doubleMyVariable(z)
```

which will assign `72` to the variable `x`. But do you see how I used `x` there? It has nothing to do with the `x` in the definition of the function.

Comment: Okay so since my choice function terminates with the creation of the userData variable, how do I go about getting the data within that variable into another function.  If it is a local variable, how do I turn it into something I can use elsewhere?

Comment: Your `choice` function has `return UserData` so in your `main` you can do something like `myData=choice()` and then `theMedianOfData=median(myData)`.

Comment: That just creates a loop where I am constantly re-entering the input within the choice() fucntion.  Lol I have so much to learn here.

Comment: You want to call `choice` from outside of your `median` and `mode` functions. But our job isn’t to debug your code in detail. Rather, try to learn to “think like a computer” and step your way through your code one line at a time.